# How to declare the result from another function in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

The first 2 functions are for the dropdown, and the last function filter function is to fetch the data into datatable. I want to use the results from function FirstName ($FirstName= [];) and LastName ($LastName= [];) for this purpose.

```
public function FirstName(Request $request)
{
    $FirstName= [];

    if($request->has('q')){
        $search = $request->q;
        $FirstName= DB::table("user")
                ->select("id","First_Name")
                ->where('First_Name','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->get();           
    }
    return response()->json($FirstName);
}

public function LastName(Request $request)
{
    $LastName= [];

    if($request->has('q')){
        $search = $request->q;
        $LastName= DB::table("user")
                ->select("id","Last_Name")
                ->where('Last_Name','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->get();           
    }

    return response()->json($Last_Name);
}


public function filter()
{

      if(!empty($FirstName))   //catch from other function
      {
       $data = DB::table('user')
         ->select('id', 'Fn', 'Ln')
         ->where('First_Name', $FirstName)
         ->where('Last_Name', $LastName)
         ->get(); 

      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('user')
         ->select('id', 'Fn', 'Ln')
         ->get();
      }
      return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);

    $data = DB::table('user')
                ->select('Last_Name','First_Name')
                ->groupBy('First_Name')
                ->groupBy('Last_Name')
                ->orderBy('First_Name', 'ASC')
                ->orderBy('Last_Name', 'ASC')
                ->get(); 
    return response()->json($data);

}
```

What I did above is put the array from function first and last name to the filter function. But i got it wrong. What should be done to fix this?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to get ? i think you trying wrong approach ?

Comment: function FirstName and LastName is where I call the data from database and function filter is where I fetch them into a datatables. The problem is I dont know how to use the data in function filter

Comment: you want use `filter()` function into user `LastName()` function ?

Comment: Basically like use the result from LastName() into filter() so I can fetch the data that I call in LastName(). LastName() and FirstName() are only to call the data without view in datatable

Comment: can you update your route file ?

Comment: Does this make sense? I only figured out this way to view data to datatable using select2

Comment: Route::get('select2-autocomplete-ajax_FirstName', 'FiltersController@FirstName');
Route::get('select2-autocomplete-ajax_LastName', 'FiltersController@LastName');
Route::get('/custom/filter', 'FiltersController@fnFilter');

Comment: FirstName,LastName function you will get many data . so why you are using `->where('First_Name', $FirstName)` , can you tell what is this param `$FirstName` ? is this response from FirstName() ?

Comment: FirstName, and LastName are the function for the dropdown (using select2) and the results of dropdown saved in an array ($LastName= []; and $FirstName= [];) as results. Then I plan to callback result into filter() to fetch into datatable

Comment: still I didn't understand your question, you want `function filter()` to access `function firstname() and lastname()` or what?

Comment: if what I think is correct then `function filter() { $fun_firstname = $this->FirstName(); if (!empty($fun_firstname)).....`